# how to Keep check box value after refresh the page for arrays like name="check[0]"

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 check boxes and I want to keep the check box value after page refresh too. I mean if I enable a check box and after I submit the form if I navigate back or refresh the page it should be enable only.

I tried this but not working.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="enable1" name="check[0]" value= "1" 
   <?php if (in_array("0", $_POST['check'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />

<input type="checkbox" id="enable2" name="check[1]" value= "1" 
   <?php if (in_array("1", $_POST['check'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
```

Please help me with this how to keep the state of check boxes after page reload

thanks..

Comment: You probably need to add [`autocomplete="off"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) to the corresponding inputs so that browsers don't mess with it.

Comment: Oh, and I didn't notice you were using `$_POST` values, but those will be lost after you navigate using back/next (or your browser will ask you to confirm resubmission, which is pretty bad). Why not just check with the current value from the database or whatnot?

Comment: i am not using database bro i have php and by using socket i am sending the values to java ,all are okay but gui side check boxes values are changing when i reload the page .
@Jeto